# Error creating a custom partition on a ESP32 microprocessor

Tags: esp32, spi, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32, flash-memory

I have an ESP32 S3 MCU with 8Mbytes. And I want to have a custom partition to store EEPROM static data. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Partition ota_0 invalid: Offset 0x1dcccc is not aligned to 0x10000
```

the partition file .csv contents are:

```
# Name,   Type, SubType,  Offset,   Size,  Flags
nvs,      data, nvs,      0x9000,   0x5000,
otadata,  data, ota,      0xe000,   0x2000,
factory,  app,  factory,  0x10000,  0x1CCCCC,
ota_0,    app,  ota_0,    0x1DCCCC, 0x1CCCCC,
ota_1,    app,  ota_1,    0x3A9998, 0x1CCCCC,
eeprom,   data, 0x99,     0x576664, 0x1000,
ffat,     data, fat,      0x577664, 0x1CCCCC,
```

Answer (score 0):

On ESP32 microprocessors there's a restriction part of the ESP32 design. One can read this here:

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/partition-tables.html

where it says "Partitions of type app have to be placed at offsets aligned to 0x10000 (64K)."

To correct the error thrown when using the partition .csv above one can simply make sure the factory partition starts at (Offset) 0x10000 and omit offsets below

```
# Name,   Type, SubType,  Offset,   Size,  Flags
nvs,      data, nvs,      0x9000,   0x5000,
otadata,  data, ota,      0xe000,   0x2000,
factory,  app,  factory,  0x10000,  0x1C0000,
ota_0,    app,  ota_0,     ,  0x1C0000,
ota_1,    app,  ota_1,     ,  0x1C0000,
eeprom,   data, 0x99,      , 0x10000,
ffat,     data, fat,       ,  0x1C0000,
```